# function prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function which I am using as a constructor. When I assign a function to it prototype and invoke the function, I only see the value `x` and not the `testMethod` which I augmented. I was expecting the augmented function also to be printed when i refer to the `this`. Is my understanding correct.

```
function Test(x){
 this.x=x;
}

Test.prototype.testMethod=function(){
  console.log(this);
}

var t= new Test(5);
t.testMethod();
```

Comment: `this` refers to the instance you've created, if you check its prototype you'll see your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because function `testMethod()` is in the *prototype*, you cannot see it in the console. It is hidden in the `__proto__` property.

If you expand `__proto__` in your console, you'll see it.

[image]